# Extract a value from log files

Tags: powershell, string-parsing

I am trying to parse logs in PowerShell from a logon monitoring product for our VDI environment. It writes a log file and it writes this line:

```
2016-12-15T14:15:02.863 INFO (0908-0bd8) [LogonMonitor::LogSummary] Logon Time: 4.03 seconds
```

What I am trying to do is parse out just "4.03" from the string and store it in an array of values. I can select the entire string from the log file by doing:

```
$LogPath = "\\file-svr\Logs\"

$strings = Select-String -path $LogPath\*.txt -pattern "[LogonMonitor::LogSummary] Logon Time:" -AllMatches -simplematch

foreach ($string in $strings) {
$found = $string -match '\d\.'
if ($found) {
    $time = $matches[1]
    $array[$i] = $time
    }
$i++
}
```

Is there a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just use a capture group in your `Select-String` pattern and grab the information.

Here a **one-liner** example:

```
$array = Select-String -path $scripts.tmp -Pattern "\[LogonMonitor::LogSummary\] Logon Time:\s*([\d|.]+)" | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

Alternative, a more **readable version**:

```
$regex = "\[LogonMonitor::LogSummary\] Logon Time:\s*([\d|.]+)"

$array = Select-String -path $scripts.tmp -Pattern $regex | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value 
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! I was way overthinking this. Thank you so much. This works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex or Template with convertfrom-string

```
#----------- Detailled example ------------------------------------------

#define temple example for define informations to extracts
$template=@"
{[date]DEvent*:2016-12-15T14:15:02.863} {LevelEvent:INFO} {TypeEvent:(0908-0bd8)} {TypeMOnitor:[LogonMonitor::LogSummary]} Logon Time: {LogonTime:4.03 seconds}
{[date]DEvent*:2017-12-15T14:15:02.863} {LevelEvent:FATAL} {TypeEvent:(090d-x01y)} {TypeMOnitor:[LogonMonitor::Log2Summary]} Logon Time: {LogonTime:123455.156 seconds}
"@


#date example, you can replace by $date=gc "yourpathfilelog"
$datas=@"
2016-12-15T14:15:02.863 INFO (0908-0bd8) [LogonMonitor::LogSummary] Logon Time: 4.03 seconds
1987-09-02T01:00:00.00 WARNING (101-0bd8) [LogonMonitor::LogxxxSummary] Logon Time: 1.00 minutes
"@


#explode data
$dataexploded=$datas | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template

#note, you can the filter like you want
$dataexploded | where {$_.LevelEvent -eq "INFO"}



#----------- short example ------------------------------------------

$template=@"
{[date]DEvent*:2016-12-15T14:15:02.863} {LevelEvent:INFO} {TypeEvent:(0908-0bd8)} {TypeMOnitor:[LogonMonitor::LogSummary]} Logon Time: {LogonTime:4.03 seconds}
{[date]DEvent*:2017-12-15T14:15:02.863} {LevelEvent:FATAL} {TypeEvent:(090d-x01y)} {TypeMOnitor:[LogonMonitor::Log2Summary]} Logon Time: {LogonTime:123455.156 seconds}
"@

gc "c:\temp\myfile.log" | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | where {$_.LevelEvent -eq "INFO"}
```